# onunload is not working without a call to function alert?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Lets say I'm trying to do the following:

```
window.onunload = handleOnClose;

function handleOnClose()
{
    logout();
    // alert('You have been signed out.');
}
```

It goes into the `handleOnClose` if I use the alert function. I don't want to alert any messages on unload. But it doesn't seem to go in the `handleOnClose` function at all if I remove the alert function.

Comment: Are you sure? Have you traced it step by step in execution?

Comment: Yes, I put a breakpoint in handleOnClose. It stops at the breakpoint if I refresh the page, but when I close the tab/browser it doesn't even go into handleOnClose. If alert is in there, it stops at the breakpoint in both cases.

Comment: I'm working with IE 8 by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `return "";` maybe ?:

```
window.attachEvent( "onunload", function(event) {
this_function_works(); // must be synchronous
event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;
});
```

And make sure `logout()` is executing **before** page closes. Meaning, you are not trying to do AJAX calls here, or submit forms. You can set or clean cookies or localStorage.

Comment: No, that didn't work. I think maybe closing the browser/tab didn't work is because when it's closed there is no instance of the page left for any javascript to be executed. So the alert() function serves as a pause in onunload for my logout() function to be executed?

Comment: wait... have you tried .onbeforeunload ? * keep in mind, it does not work in older versions Opera.

Comment: Yes, I did. Basically, in onbeforeunload I return the generic message 'Are you sure you want to leave the page.' And if they click OK, the browser/tab will be closed and I log them out in onunload, if they hit Cancel they will stay on the current page.

Comment: Try new solution, it works in IE9 in IE8 mode.. hopefully it also works in IE8.

Comment: Before we go on, thanks for helping me. From your code, I'm assuming this_function_works() is where I should call the logout() function. But lets make sure that the logout() function is not the problem. Is there a way that I can test that this_fucntion_works() is actually being executed? Because I tried to debug from IE, but the debug window closes as soon as I close the browser so I'm not sure if the function in onunload is actually called.

Comment: Yes, to test it, you can save cookies, -  try my code, thought its VERY ugly - http://pastebin.com/VA5zcUSD

Comment: Yep, it does work. The problem is with the logout() function. I dug deeper and it uses DWR to make calls to Java functions to log out the user. Why can't we do AJAX on onunload? So is there anyway around this if the logout() function uses DWR/AJAX?

Comment: In theory, you might try synchronous XHR or fetching 1px image to trigger logout on a server... don't know if it will work, because in firefox, for example, such calls are canceled, when the page is in process of unloading. But really, you should rethink the whole scheme, because what happens if, say, user reboots his PC ? Will he stay logged forever ?

Comment: There is a timeout set on the server side, so the user will be logged out after a certain amount of time. What I'm trying to do here is to save the users from themselves. We have been telling the users repeatedly to make sure to hit the sign out button when they're done, not just by hitting the X button to close the browser because this will keep them logged in and lock up a license. So I thought I could log them out when they don't listen and just close the browser without hitting the sign out button first. I will try to come up with anther solution, thanks for all your help.